# Simple graphql client in c# using RestSharp - The underlying connection was closed error

Tags: c#, graphql

I have a graphql server written in NodeJS + ExpressJS + MongoDB, and I can run the following mutation on it fine:

[image]

I need to use the graphql api on a C# desktop application. So, I have decided to create a simple GraphQL Client in C#, which looks like this:

https://github.com/latheesan-k/simple-graphql-client/blob/master/SimpleGraphQLClient/SimpleGraphQLClient.cs

I use it like this:

```
var client = new SimpleGraphQLClient("https://tweetserver.dynamic-dns.net/graphql");

var query = @"
    mutation {
        signup(
            email: $email
            fullName: $fullName
            password: $password
            avatar: $avatar
            username: $username
        ) {
            token
        }
    }
";

dynamic signup = client.Execute(query, new
{
    email = "test-user3@domain.com",
    fullName = "Test User",
    password = "123456",
    avatar = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/0.jpg",
    username = "testuser3"
});

if (signup != null && signup.error == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine((string)signup.token);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error - {0}", signup.error);
}
```

When I run the tester, I get the following error:

> Error - The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error
>   occurred on a send.

I know the graphql api end point is valid and working as intended (see first screenshot):

https://tweetserver.dynamic-dns.net/graphql
https://tweetserver.dynamic-dns.net/graphiql

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured it out. I'm using the LetsEncrypt free SSL and the nginx rules from https://cipherli.st and it was the NginX (reverse proxy running the ssl + rules) that rejected the connection from my c# graphql client via RestSharp.

To fix the error, you just need to add this to your app:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 
    SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | 
    SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | 
    SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```